# How to prevent showing ion-option-button in IonicFramework?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I use different list in one page with each list have some Option button,
you can take a look at my codepen : `[http://codepen.io/harked/pen/WvMgXg][1]`

If we swipe the first card, it will show the option button.
If we swipe the second card, it will also show the option button.
Is there any way to prevent Option-Button to show while the other in another card is showing?

I mean the problem is like this pict : http://www.nanonimos.com/IonOption.jpg

Anyone? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take the backticks away from the link and it will be clickable :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like Ionic have a way to do this right now. What we need is a listener on the option buttons being display, at which point you can close all others, but that listener doesn't exist.

You could build custom functionality and listen for swipe events on each ion-list item, but this is likely to be a little buggy. Alternatively dig into the framework and try and emit a custom event on the same trigger than Ionic uses.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an ng-repeat when working with lists in Ionic. You can easily disable Option buttons using ng-show as in this codepen.

```
[http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vORyaz?editors=101']
```

Comment: Its not suitable with my case @Samarth. I use a 'card' that : -can be swipe to show the option button and -can be click to show the description.